# UITextView attributed Alignment and size

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

First assume math is correct.

```
let textViewText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "34\n+ 10\n+ 32344\n= 23424")
```

Im using a Textview to display input from the user. To make it easier to read I'm trying to get the text format like this

> ```
>       34 
>  +    10 
>  + 32344 
>  = 23424
> ```

The other issue I'm having is with wrapping. Is there a way to resize each line to fit on its line?

> ```
>       34 
>  = 23424
> 4356356
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Is your text dynamic or static? If static, then all you need to do is to put the correct amount of spacing between your numbers and plus signs and then right justify the text.

```
self.textView.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "34\n+      10\n+ 32344\n= 23424")
self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
```

Result:

[image: RESULT]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a right-aligned tab stop in your paragraph style, and separating your operators and values with a tab.

```
let string = "\t34\n+\t10\n+\t32344\n=\t23424"

let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .Right, location: 200, options: [:])]

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes:[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph])
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch10p507tabStops)   Found this while looking for examples. It looks like what i want to do will require quite a bit of work.